# How to run make in Vim, open results in split window and show the compilation time?

Tags: makeprg

I would like to run `:make` in Vim, while also allowing the user to edit a file while we're waiting for the compilation to finish, then when the compilation is finished open the result in a split window (which I know by itself would be done with `:make | copen`) with how long it took for the make to run (preferably in a human-readable format, e.g., 5m 32s instead of 332s). Is this possible? I'm guessing using the UNIX time command I could edit my Makefile to do the time measurement, but does Vim have the ability to time the make command itself?

Comment: Vim cannot do things asynchronously, so AFAIK this is not possible without a heavy workaround. Something like call make manually in a background shell, output results to file, start a timer that continually looks for the file and opens it in in a new window. Even this won't have all the benefits of actually calling `:make` though (Like being able to jump to errors and such).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, with Vim8.

1. First you'll need to register the current time with `reltime()` function.
2. Then, start a job that'll run the content of `&makeprg` with `$*` replaced with the target you wish to used (it may be an empty string). Don't forget to register a hook that'll listen for any line produced by the compilation. You'll certainly wish to add it to `:caddexpr`.
3. And also, you'll have to register the close callback. In this one you'll know whether the compilation has succeeded, and you'll compare the new `reltime()` with the registered one.

Note: that while I don't display the compilation time in [lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib)+[build-tools-wrapper](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper), it's easy to add (actually I display it when we put the [`lh/btw/job_build.vim` autoload plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/job-compile/autoload/lh/btw/job_build.vim) in verbose mode).

Comment: I'm not an advanced Vim scripter, so I have no idea how to do step 1, 2 or 3. Could you boil it down to a set of commands or additions to my `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: First hit in a Google search: https://github.com/djmoch/vim-makejob

Comment: @Vitor That creates a split window during the build process but it doesn't show it after the build is completed (i.e., as soon as the build is completed it closes the compilation split window), nor does it show the compilation time.

Comment: @Brenton Horne. The thing is that a correct solution will take a couple hundred lines -- see my third link. This is not something that fits nicely in a `vimrc`. If you're not afraid of big plugins I can add an option in my build-tool-wrappers plugin to display the compilation time even in non verbose mode.

Comment: @LucHermitte That option in your plugin sounds great, please. If it works I'll be happy to accept this answer.

Comment: @BrentonHorne My quickfix window is properly updated after `'makeprg'` completes and my error jump commands appear to work properly. The build time could be fixed on the tool side, by adding some shell script commands to your build script. OTH, you could also create an issue on the plugin's Github to see if its maintainer would add that option.

Comment: @BrentonHorne. I've just checked. Actually, I did already display the compilation time -- I've haven't compiled anything in a while and I've forgotten since then ^^'